# Unable to render svg through JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Trying to create an SVG minus icon using SVG tags dynamically using JS.
The same gets rendered as expected when directly used in the body of the HTML.

Could you please help me understand what's the problem here?

JS fiddle code for reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/w92ucf05/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG</h1>

<style>
 .svg-circleplus { stroke: green; }
</style>

<div id="demo"></div>
<!-- Expected svg -->
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="1em" height="1em" class="svg-circleplus"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 7.5;"></circle><line x1="32.5" y1="50" x2="67.5" y2="50" style="stroke-width: 5"></line></svg>

<script>
//Script to render the smae SVG
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
    svg.setAttribute('viewbox', '0 0 100 100');
    svg.setAttribute('width', '1em');
    svg.setAttribute('height', '1em');
    svg.setAttribute("class","svg-circleplus");

var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    circle.setAttribute('cx', 50);
    circle.setAttribute('cy', 50);
    circle.setAttribute('r', 45);
    circle.setAttribute('style', 'fill: none; stroke-width: 7.5;' );
    svg.appendChild(circle);

var line = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'line');
    line.setAttribute("x1", 32.5);
    line.setAttribute("y1", 50);
    line.setAttribute("x2", 67.5);
    line.setAttribute("y2", 50);
    line.setAttribute('style', 'stroke-width: 5' );
    svg.appendChild(line);
    
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(svg);
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript is cool, you have a CSS problem, just add a width and height to your SVG and it will show up.

```
<style>
    .svg-circleplus { stroke: green; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
</style>
```

```js
//Script to render the smae SVG
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
    svg.setAttribute('viewbox', '0 0 100 100');
    svg.setAttribute('width', '1em');
    svg.setAttribute('height', '1em');
    svg.setAttribute("class","svg-circleplus");


var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    circle.setAttribute('cx', 50);
    circle.setAttribute('cy', 50);
    circle.setAttribute('r', 45);
    circle.setAttribute('style', 'fill: none; stroke-width: 7.5;' );
    svg.appendChild(circle);

var line = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'line');
    line.setAttribute("x1", 32.5);
    line.setAttribute("y1", 50);
    line.setAttribute("x2", 67.5);
    line.setAttribute("y2", 50);
    line.setAttribute('style', 'stroke-width: 5' );
    svg.appendChild(line);
    
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(svg);
```

```css
svg{
  stroke: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just to understand - height and width was already set while creating the svg. Not sure why should we mention it again in the css.

Comment: Your are using `svg.setAttribute('height', '1em')`, you should use `svg.setAttribute('style', 'width: 1em; height: 1em;')`